# Spring not able to autowire repository in Controller

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, autowired

I am new to Spring and was trying to get a simple webapp up and running using Spring Data and Spring MVC.

Here is my Controller:

```
package org.springbyexample.web.servlet.mvc;

@Controller
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserRepository getRepository() {
        return userRepository;
    }

    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    // code removed
 }
```

Here is my repository:

```
package org.springbyexample.web.orm.repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, String> {

    Users findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Here is my webmvc-context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="org.springbyexample.web.servlet.mvc" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springbyexample.web.security" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="org.springbyexample.web.orm org.springbyexample.web.beans" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:view-controller path="/index.html" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/demodb" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.springbyexample.web.orm" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

On running this using maven-jetty-plugin, I get the following error:

```
2015-04-02 16:08:39.272:WARN::Nested in    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springbyexample.web.orm.repository.UserRepository org.springbyexample.web.servlet.mvc.PersonController.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springbyexample.web.orm.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springbyexample.web.orm.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
```

This is my User entity:

```
package org.springbyexample.web.beans;

@Entity
public class Users {

   private Timestamp activationDate;
   private Timestamp registrationDate;
   private int isActive;
   private String role;
   private String email;
   private int userId;
   @Id
   private String username;
   private String password;
   private String fullname;
   private String tranauth;
   private String clientPIN;

   // Getters and Setters for all of them
```

}

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Post your repo impl and try moving the @Repo annotation to your impl rather than interface. Generally, impl are annotated.

Comment: Does your component scan pick up your Repository package?

Comment: @minion Spring Data repository interfaces usually don't have explicit implementations.

Comment: My bad. Didn't notice it.

Comment: Your configured JPA basepackege looks strange: `base-package="org.springbyexample.web.orm org.springbyexample.web.beans"` -- try to use only one package

Comment: Post your User entity.

Comment: Done. Added the user entity.

Comment: Just follow the below mentioned steps which is posted by me as answer.

Comment: @Steve: It looks its not able to pick it up. But my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) seems to pick up the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="org.springbyexample.web.orm org.springbyexample.web.beans" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"/>
```

is not correct.

If your repository in only under package org.springbyexample.web.orm
Then just remove org.springbyexample.web.beans so it will look like as

As well in your controller remove getter and setter as its not required autowire enoguh to do the magic.

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="org.springbyexample.web.orm" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"/>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you need the getters and setters as the repository variable is private?

Comment: In class `PersonController ` you have to use `userRepository` instance. I mean to say in same class or you accessing `userRepository`  beyond to `PersonController `. If it is like it means its not good coding standards.

Comment: I am getting a new exception now: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class org.springbyexample.web.beans.Users while initiating the repository in the controller.

Comment: No, I am not accessing userRepository outside PersonController. But my question was doesn't spring also use the setter method for setting the variable?

Comment: How do we specify the entity for a repository, looks like its not able to pick that up.

Comment: you are using @autowired so no need to go for setter.for this exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class org.springbyexample.web.beans.Users` you first move your Users class to package org.springbyexample.web.orm.repository and try Make sure your are using `<jpa:repositories base-package="org.springbyexample.web.orm.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"/>` if it works then in next step move to other package with upcoming inputs.

Comment: @n3o The "not a managed type" means that you don't have your JPA setup (Hibernate?) working properly; the JPA provider also needs to know where your entity classes are.

Comment: So, your fix of moving the entity class to the same package as the repository did the trick (although, I had to make a couple more changes as well to finally get it to work). But, after so much of doing things automatically, you would expect Spring to do this tiny bit also. Is there an annotation or an XML config to let the repository know where the entity classes are?

Comment: I always put my entity outside the repository package as its best coding standards however I have never faced such issue like what you faced above.I think if everything working for you now just try to move your entity class in other package I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Enable` annotations must be specified on `@Configuration` classes. Putting it on your controller will have no effect. You may also need to specify a base package if the repository interfaces are in a different package tree from the annotated configuration class.

(Additionally, you shouldn't annotate repository interfaces; just use the annotation for actual DAO classes when you want Spring Data to modify the handling.)

Comment: I dont have a @Configuration class. What is it for? Should I create one? Yes my repository is in a different package from the controller, but isn't that take care of by the <jpa> configuration in my webmvc-context.xml?

Comment: @n3o its not required.

Comment: @n3o `@Configuration` is the Java-based alternative to XML configuration, and `@EnableJpaRepositories` is only effective when used on a class annotated with `@Configuration`. Since it looks like you did include `jpa:repositories` in your XML (I missed it), you don't need the annotation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the below annotation in the class which has a public static void main(String... args) if you have one. or just try adding it to the controller.

```
  @Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue is resolved by changing(moving) the

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/root-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

to

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>{code}
```